# Spring boot application return me : 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp

while trying to send email via my spring boot application i got this error :

```
failures; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1);
nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)
```

My Spring boot application is generated with jhipster and here is my application-dev.yml config for mail config :

```
mail:   
  host: mail.example.com
  port: 587
  username: support@example.com
  password: ************
```

**NB : example.com is just an example for not sharing confidential data, my config is correct i have tested it with and working great but not on my spring boot application**

Comment: You need to use actual SMTP configurations, example.com does not exist.

Comment: of course i did !!! example.com is just an example for not sharing confidential data, thanks for your comment dude

Comment: Why tagging it as jhipster? It's only spring-boot configuration. Your question lacks some details like what is your mail server (public or private)? Have you tested your configuration using `telnet` command or a mail client? You show only an extract of your application properties so we don't know whether it's correctly indented and under `spring`, it can be anything? Have you set a breakpoint in debugger to check the contents of `MailProperties`?

Comment: thanks for your answer you are right there is no need to tag jhipster on that question, as you said it's a spring-boot config problem. and i did test it as you said and i found that i forget to add 'mail.smtp.starttls.enable : true' and 'mail.smtp.starttls.auth : true' best regards for you @GaëlMarziou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After review i found that i forgot to add some mail config in my `application-dev.yml` :

`mail.smtp.starttls.enable : true` and `mail.smtp.starttls.auth : true`

mail config should look like :

```
mail:   
  host: mail.example.com
  port: 587
  username: support@example.com
  password: ************
  properties:
    mail:
      smtp:
        auth: true
        starttls:
          enable: true
```

Answer (score 2):

I have provided a sample below.
Showing how I send emails with `spring-boot`

add the starter mail dependency in your `pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add the below bean in your Application class :

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSenderImpl customJavaMailSenderImpl(){

    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost(host);
    mailSender.setPort(port);
     
    mailSender.setUsername(username);
    mailSender.setPassword(password);
     
    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
     
    return mailSender;

}
```

See an example, using the `customJavaMailSenderImpl` bean below :

```
@Service
public class emailSender{
   
   @Autowired
   JavaMailSenderImpl customJavaMailSenderImpl;

   public void mailWithAttachment() throws Exception {
    
    MimeMessage message = customJavaMailSenderImpl.createMimeMessage();
      
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true,"utf-8");
     
    helper.setTo("abc@example.com");
    helper.setSubject("test");
    helper.setText("hello test", true);
    helper.setFrom("abd@example.com", "John Doe");
      
    
 
    customJavaMailSenderImpl.send(message);
    
 }


}
```